# SonarQube complains about checking for List#contains in Collection<? extends Integer>

Tags: java

SonarQube complains about the following piece of code

```
public static Predicate<ClassA> createPredicate(Collection<? extends Integer> list) {
    return classA -> list.contains(classA.getId());
}
```

by saying that "A `Collection<? extends Integer>` cannot contain a `int`".

Im using a `Collection<? extends Integer>` here give a hint about this method not adding elements to the `Collection`.

Is SonarQube speaking the truth here and i should use a `Collection<Integer>` instead?

Comment: Does the warning go away when you make `list` a `Collection<Integer>`?

Comment: @arne.b Yes it does, and thats the interesting about it

Comment: And if you box explicitly the int to Integer which result ?      `return classA -> list.contains(Integer.valueOf(classA.getId());`

Comment: Tried this as well, but it results in "Unnecessary boxing `Integer.valueOf(classA.getId())`", seems like this is a dilemma

Comment: not used `SonarQube` before but note that  `Collection<? extends Integer>` doesn't make sense as `Integer` is `final` so `Collection<Integer>` is more appropriate.

Comment: It sounds really a not meaningful message as obviously a `Collection<? extends Integer>` can contain `Integer`s. It can even only contain them as Integer is final.

Comment: Thats a good hint, that you for pointing that out. So the best solution would be to ignore that issue?

Comment: Not necessary because  I am a little annoyed with that "here give a hint about this method not adding elements to the Collection." It is  not a clear way to do that. If the method is provided to clients, specify it in the javadoc if it makes sense and use simply `Collection<Integer>`. `Collection<? extends Integer>` seems awkward as you expect to accept subclass of Integer as parameter but you will never pass them.

Comment: No, the use of that is purely to give the users of that class a hint that the collection is not modified by this method. (I could use any other type as well, for example `Collection<? extends ClassB>`). So the best way to provide that hint would be javadoc instead?

Comment: What the use for `<? extends Integer>` when `Integer` class is final ?

Comment: Of course. And still. Is it really useful ? `createPredicate()` naming is meaningful : it creates and returns a Predicate. Which kind of client could expect that it will modify the List passed as argument ? The reasoning seems a little bit overkill.

Comment: We were given the information to use `? extends Class` to give users the hint that the `Collection` is not modified. Correct me if this is wrong, but this is what we were tought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My hunch is that SonarQube tries to be too clever by half here.

A few observations:

1. A `Collection<? extends Integer>` can contain `Integer`s. Since `Integer` is a final class, it can, in fact, contain nothing else, so for your own sanity you might as well use a `Collection<Integer>` (unless your actual use case is more complex in ways I cannot yet imagine).
2. A `Collection<? extends Integer>` cannot contain an `int` since that is a primitive type, so SonarQube is literally correct here, but since an `int` will be boxed, the expression still makes sense.
3. SonarQube accounts for the possibility of boxing, which is why the warning goes away when you use a `Collection<Integer>` (which literally cannot contain an `int` either, of course). However, it only accounts for the case of the generic type being the boxed version of the looked up type [(source)](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/d6b860e35e4135a68de2b3e37ff62c5df17969c6/java-checks/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/checks/CollectionInappropriateCallsCheck.java#L120), not the generic type being a subtype thereof. (Iirc, all boxed primitive types are final, so the authors of the rule may have found it irrelevant to make special provisions for `<? extends BoxedPrimitive>`.)

If the latter is true, it should be safe to ignore the warning, but even safer to use a `Collection<Integer>` in the first place.

Comment: That explains it really well, thank you a lot for that.